# JSON dump ERROR - The payload sent is not a valid json document

Tags: python, json, post, request, payload

```py
def build_payload(variable_1, variable_2, variable_3):
    # read the .txt file using pandas
    df = pd.read_csv('./2. gateway-lora/20230116.txt', sep='\t')
    payload={}
    for i in range(len(df)):
        f_cnt = int(df["f_cnt"].values[i])
        rssi = int(df["rssi"].values[i])
        snr = int(df["snr"].values[i])
        payload = {variable_1: f_cnt, variable_2: rssi, variable_3: snr}
        #payload = {"{}".format(variable_1): f_cnt, "{}".format(variable_2): rssi, "{}".format(variable_3): snr}
        payload = json.dumps({"f_cnt": f_cnt, "rssi": rssi, "snr": snr })
        print (payload)
        post_request(payload)
    return payload
```

Without the json.dumps it is sending {'f_cnt': 1061, 'rssi': -104, 'snr': -7}.

Expected with the Ubidots API : https://docs.ubidots.com/v1.6/reference/send-data-to-a-device

With json.dumps it is therefore applying theses changes but at the execution and POST request it is returning : "The payload sent is not a valid json document".

How could I solve this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: could you show us the output after using json.dumps?

Comment: There are pages where you can just paste your JSON and check if it's valid

Comment: @Kulasangar Here is the output :

{"f_cnt": 1061, "rssi": -104, "snr": -7}

400 {'code': 400001, 'message': 'The payload sent is not a valid json document.'}

Comment: Just a guess but try sending [{"f_cnt": 1061, "rssi": -104, "snr": -7}]

Comment: @Pingu it is not considering it as a JSON too

Comment: Is `post_request()` your own code or from a library?

Comment: @ivvija @Kulasangar @Pingu It seems that afterwards it was working with sending `{'f_cnt': 1061, 'rssi': -104, 'snr': -7}` which is somehow strange because it does not fit the expected syntax. Otherwise, Ubidots free plan only includes 4000 dots/day. As result I have created a new account and it was solved.

One more time thank you for your help